# Place text between sidebar Wordpress widgets

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget

Where can I the code to add "OR" between two of my WP sidebar widgets?  I understand I could easily add a text widget and place the word "OR" in there.  However, when I do that, my CSS styling for sidebar widgets has a background-color and a border.  I do not want "OR" to have the same styling.  Basically I just want text between the two widgets I have on my site.

Can we place the "OR" only once, just incase more widgets get added?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to target that sidebar widget specifically and override the background CSS.

Comment: @jprofitt you are completely right!  Thank you, I feel like an idiot now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin [Magic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-widgets/). It offers a widget named **Unfiltered Text** which does exactly what the name says: It prints only the content you put in there.
It doesn’t use the `before_widget` and `after_widget` parameters, so you can use it to create any content with full control.

Disclosure: I’m the author of the plugin.